# HTML video with fixed height and adjusted width without missing parts

Tags: html, css, html5-video, media-player

I'm actually only able to do the opposite (fixed width, but adjusted height). But whatever I try, it doesn't keep whole content and cuts some piece.

HTML:

```
    <div class="player" id="player">
      <video id="myVideo" class="player__video viewer" preload="none">
        <source src="video.mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.player {
  max-width: 70%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a height and  `display: inline-block;` with `width: auto`

```css
.player {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="player" id="player">
  <video id="myVideo" class="player__video viewer" preload="none">
        <source src="video.mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually it still cuts a piece of video below. I want to make sure that to the fixed height will be shown complete footage and width will be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: @Stanyko `height: 200px` is for example. Did you set the height needed for your actual video?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I need to have adjusted width according set height.

Comment: @Stanyko width in this case should be automatic i.e as wide as content

Answer (score 0):

I recently started with CSS and HTML(like 2 days ago).
But this seems to work, not sure if this is what you meant.

```html
<div>
      <video id="myVideo" class="player_video_viewer" controls>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

```css
.player_video_viewer {
  max-width: 70%; /*or "width"*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this doesn't provide the expected results.